# Cucumber feature failing when rendering template with confusing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, bdd

I'm trying to make my tests pass, but cucumber is failing with a very confusing error, probably template related, that I'm not able to understand and fix.

Here is my Gemfile and Gemfile.lock:

https://gist.github.com/ngw/dada0c0658a9ef8b5573

You can assume that everything is on its latest version as of today, 28 March 2015, including rails, cucumber, ruby (2.2.0p0), database_cleaner, and so on.

The view that fails to render is a devise view that renders just fine on the browser.

Here is the exception raised:

```
Background:                # features/users/sign_up.feature:6
  Given I am not logged in # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:9

Scenario: User signs up with valid data          # features/users/sign_up.feature:9
  When I sign up with valid user data            # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:13
  undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    (in /Users/ngw/petswantpats/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css) (ActionView::Template::Error)
  ./app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml___302582815389802583_70306431437360'
  ./features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:6:in `sign_up'
  ./features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:15:in `/^I sign up with valid user data$/'
  ./features/support/database_cleaner.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>'
  features/users/sign_up.feature:10:in `When I sign up with valid user data'
Then I should see a successful sign up message # features/step_definitions/user_steps.rb:18
```

Here are the incriminated views:

https://gist.github.com/ngw/95c0a0e6db86cfa0357f

Here is the content of application.css.scss:

https://gist.github.com/ngw/ab766e0cfb5167d2d76a

The failing step:

```
def sign_up
  visit '/users/sign_up'
end
```

Is it something JS related? I'm using poltergeist with capybara, my env.rb has:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

If I use launchy to open it in the browser I have a white page (???) and no other usable information in my test.log...

Can someone help me on how to debug this? TIA

Comment: Can you post the contents of `stylesheets/application.css`?